# Countdown with stop button

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to build a countdown timer and it kind of worked, but when I changed the code to make it more readable and when I added the stop button function it got a bit buggy. I fiddled around a lot, but I can't get it working again.
The problem I have is, that the countdown starts from the time when the page has loaded and not from the number assigned to "sessTime".
Here is the code (i know it is a lot, sorry):

```
var startButton = document.getElementById('btnStart');
var stopButton = document.getElementById('btnStop');
var sessionTime = parseInt(document.getElementById('sessNum').innerHTML); //gets duration number
var sessLength = Date.parse(new Date()) + sessionTime * 60 * 1000;

startButton.onclick = function() {
  if (!sessTimer) { 
   startButton.value="Stop";
   var sessTimer = setInterval(runSess, 1000);
  }else{
    startButton.value="Start";
    clearInterval(sessTimer);   
  }
}; 

function runSess() {  
  var timeLeft = sessLength - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((timeLeft / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((timeLeft / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((timeLeft / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);  

  document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = ('0' + hours).slice(-2);
  document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = ('0' + minutes).slice(-2);
  document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = ('0' + seconds).slice(-2);

  if (timeLeft <= 0) {
    clearInterval(sessTimer);
  }
}
```

This code is part of a [codepen project](https://codepen.io/phantazee/pen/YVQpLv) of mine. Maybe the context helps to answer this question.

Thanks in advance, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared sessTimer inside the scope of your function.

```
startButton.onclick = function() {
  if (!sessTimer) { 
   startButton.value="Stop";
   var sessTimer = setInterval(runSess, 1000);
```

With the code above, every time you enter the function, sessTimer is undefined and you declare a new one. What you can do is the following :

```
var sessTimer = null;
startButton.onclick = function() {
  if (!sessTimer) { 
   startButton.value="Stop";
   sessTimer = setInterval(runSess, 1000);

  }else{
    startButton.value="Start";
    clearInterval(sessTimer);   
    sessTimer = null;
  }
};
```

Into you function, you also need to change your button :

```
  if (timeLeft <= 0) {
    startButton.value="Start";
    clearInterval(sessTimer);
  }
```

Comment: First of all: wow, thanks a lot! As you can see I am clearly a beginner, so this helps a lot. I have one question though: I just tried your solution, but now it won't count down and only updates when I click the button. Do you have any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: I misunderstood a bit the code. I've also made mistakes, I updated my answer

Comment: @JanEgbers I forked your codepen and updated it to allow to stop when the user has stopped it. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aWwJxv

Comment: Thank you so much, this helps a lot understanding the topic